# How can I handle attunement for timebounded adventures that might not have short rests?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, one-shot, attunement

I will be running [Strahd Must Die Tonight!](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/359-strahd-must-die-tonight-how-to-play-ravenloft-in-a), a timed, one-shot adventure for D&D 5e. In previous games of it, due to the real and in-game time constraints and lack of short rests, I have handwaved attunement and allowed attunement to magic items just before the finale.

Are there any rules that speed up attunement that should be considered? Are there any mechanics of attunement to take into account for one-shots? Are there any compelling reasons not to allow players attune to items pivotal to the game?

Comment: That one-shot is bound by 4 IRL hours, not 4 in-game hours. I don't see a reason why they couldn't snag a short-rest during play.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Consider using the Epic Heroism rest variant

### Make short rests shorter.

(Disclaimer: My answer primarily handles the generic question you present. Its applicability to the particular one-shot you are running is not considered.)

In the *Dungeon Master's Guide*, page 267, are some optional rules which provide a variation on the typical resting rules. This would appear suited to a one-shot where time is short but action is plentiful.

> This variant uses a short rest of 5 minutes and a long rest of 1 hour.

This variant rule also suggests a clause to limit the spell slots which spellcasters recover from a 1 hour long rest.

Of course, as with all the variant rules presented in this chapter of the DMG, you are encouraged to modify it to suit your table. If you think that allowing players to receive the full benefits of rests in such a short in-game time would be too disruptive, you could instead consider only shortening the time it takes to attune to an item and leaving the other effects of resting unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

**There are no in-game time constraints**

Read it again. Nowhere does it mention any in-game time limits. Indeed it explicitly says the players “have “four hours until planar midnight,” which sidesteps the issue of game time passing differently than real time.”

So they can take as many short (or long) rests subject to the DM’s rulings and the time it takes to say “we take a short/long rest” and do the paperwork in real time. Given the nature of the atmosphere you are trying to evoke, I wouldn’t allow long rests by as many short ones as they want.

Comment: That **is** an in-game time constraint. Four in-game hours!

Comment: The section you quoted is about an in-game character appearing, in the game, and announcing a four hour time limit. Is that *not* an in-game time limit?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica no, it is specifically about Strahd appearing every real-world hour.